# How to add authentication info in java client?

Tags: java, authentication, basic-authentication

How to configure authentication in a java client, I tried creating new `Authenticator` object & calling it is set Default method, but I am still getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Authentication failure
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1096)
    at UrlProxy.main(UrlProxy.java : 54)
```

Please let me know if I need to set any other additional properties.
I am opening the connection to my target site using `HttpUrlconnection` class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem in my case was, the server is expecting NTLM Proxy whereas I am sending credentials in plaintext, after changing this it worked fine.